# Is there anyway to ameliorate the Logic App limit on managed identity in a subscription?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Is there anyway to ameliorate the Logic App limit on managed identity in a subscription?

Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities#azure-logic-apps) have the limit as 250

*Number of logic apps that have a managed identity in an Azure subscription per region   250*

Is there anyway to handle this? ... *as we're already getting close to that limit, and we're now doing all our integration with logic apps*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response we got from the Logic App team is the limit is "soft", so it's possible to increase on a case-by-case basis

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to contact Microsoft support to see for possible ways to circumvent these limits. 
The way I manage this is by creating reusable logic apps which work with managed identities and call these logic apps in parent workflows